# Split DocumentRoot using Apache Alias per request path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I'm trying to slowly take over an existing website, route per route. I found Apache's `Alias(Match)` which seems to allow me to set a different (content) document root per request. But I'm failing with trailing slashes and more complex paths.

My goal now is to have the old website serve everything as it is used to. And to have a new website, serving a first specific request, say `/foo` and `/foo/*`.

I have my vhost setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    UseCanonicalName on

    AliasMatch ^/foo/(.*)$ /www/new/$1
    AliasMatch ^/foo$ /www/new/$1
    <Directory /www/new/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /www/old
    <Directory /www/old/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In both directories I have an `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The `index.php`'s show 'old' or 'new' depending on their directory.

What happens to the different routes I test:

- When requesting `example.com/bar` it shows 'old'.
- When requesting `example.com/foo` it redirects too `/foo/`, and then shows 'new'.
- When requesting `example.com/foo/bar` it shows 'old'.

I don't want the forced redirect of `/foo` to `/foo/`. And I want `/foo/bar` to show 'new'.

I've been following [Apache's `mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) to get the multiple `AliasMatch` directives to catch anything after `/foo` but apparently that's not working correctly. Also, I don't read anything there of the trailing slash being added magically.

Anyone knows the magic tricks?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this by adjusting the Alias to point to the index.php directly:

```
AliasMatch ^/foo/(.*)$ /www/new/index.php
AliasMatch ^/foo$ /www/new/index.php
```

Then `/bar` and anything else goes to the old website, and `/foo`, `/foo/` and `/foo/bar` goes to the new website.

There's two downsides to this method:

- The `.htaccess` in the new website is skipped completely. But as I mainly use that for letting the index.php pick up every route, that's fine for now.
- Frontend resources like css/js go to the old website. Fix that with another simple alias: `example.com/frontend/app.css` + `Alias /frontend /www/new/public_html/frontend`.